# Laravel - Attempt to read property "id" on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Hope you can help me. I'm trying a simple loop in a Laravel blade view and trying to access some data through a relationship.

The DD below outputs `1` as expected, but the echo in the h5 produces the error in the title. I'm stumped!

```
@forelse($user_adverts as $user_advert)
    {{ dd($user_advert->advertLogs->first()->id) }}
    <h5 class="card-title">£ {{ $user_advert->advertLogs->first()->id }}</h5>
@empty
    <p>No adverts yet :(</p>
@endforelse
```

If I `{{ dd($user_advert->advertLogs->first()) }}` I see the model: App\Models\AdvertLog

I'm just confused why I can't output a single column without a null error? Usually that means there is no relationship I thought? I know this is going to be a simple one - your help is appreciated!

Comment: probably because you're looping over many `$user_adverts` and it doesn't exist for one of the later models in the loop

Comment: what happen when your remove the `first()` ?

Comment: @BenGooding oh dear you're absolutely right. I had 2 $user_advert rows but the second one didn't have a link to advertLog. My DD worked on the first one of course, but the error was being thrown the second time round the loop! Thank you so much. I was so focussed on the code I really needed to look at my test data!

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the error by changing the card title like this

```
{{ $user_advert->advertLogs->first()?->id }}
```

The id will be displayed if you have one, and nothing if there is no advertLogs.
Not sure if this is want you intented to do though.